# How to transfer the control from one part of the main to another part of the main in java?

Tags: java

I was writing a program which required me to display a set of statements to the
user then ask him whether he would like to return to the main screen.
But since I was using a case I could not transfer control back to the code before it.I want to know how I can do it.Here's the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class main
    {
       public static void main() throws IOException
       {
            InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
            System.out.println("START");
            int ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            switch(ch)
            {
                 case 1:System.out.println("HI");
                        break;
                       /*I want a way to transfer the control from the case 
                         such that it is transferred to
                         the print statement START.*/

            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: wrap you entire code in main method inside a do-while loop.

Comment: @Thilo, not quite dead, just uncommon. See this, for example: [control flow constructs](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/control-flow/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. One would be to have it in a loop and keep asking the user whether he wants to have a new input.

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class main
  {
  public static void main() throws IOException
  {
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    int ch;
    int input;
    while(true)
    {
    System.out.println("Do you want to return to main screen. Press 1 for Yes, 0 for No");
    input = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(input == 1)
    {
     ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        switch(ch)
        {
             case 1:System.out.println("HI");
                    break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
    break;
    }
    }
```

Even the answer above mine is correct but this might give user more usability.
Hope this helps !!

Comment: This code will not run, 1 is an integer not a boolean so the while condidtion fails, also don't know why you're using ch when you've already got that value in the variable "input"

Comment: bro while(1) means an infinite loop in Java. Plzz check. And secondly i used ch so that his main functionality will not change and as such he might be using more than 1 case so better to have two variables.

Comment: Your code does not compile for the reason I stated above, This may work in other languages but in Java, 1 is not a boolean and the condition in the while statement must evaluate to a boolean.

Comment: Ok for java we have to right while(true) , for C and python this works.I have changed it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use loop, so that control will be again at first `System.out.println()`, if `ch == 1`.

```
import java.io.*;
public class main
{
   public static void main() throws IOException
   {
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        int ch;
        do {
            System.out.println("START");
            int ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            switch(ch)
            {
                 case 1:System.out.println("HI");
                        break;
            }
       } while (ch == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not work, you've defined the local variable ch twice.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and compile (I've changed the main method signature so you can try it).

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        int ch;
        do {
            System.out.println("START");
            ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            switch(ch)
            {
                 case 1:System.out.println("HI");
                 break;
            }
       } while (ch == 1);
        System.out.println("1 was not entered, exiting");
    }   
}
```